# Python write file smb path

Tags: python, smb

I´ve found many solutions here, but none of them finish my little problem. 
I have to write and read a file on a smb directory.

I´ve tried to use "Z:\path\file.txt" as the share was mapped, and it doesn´t worked. 
Than i´ve found here some samples saying that i should only use the server name or ip and path to write.

So \192.168.0.1\path\file.txt is ok. But now, im having to write it in a authenticated path.
How do i authenticate the python script to write the file in the current path?

Thanks in advance! ^^

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `net use`:

```
net use Z: \\COMPUTER\sharename password /User:COMPUTER\username
```

This is the help:

```
C:\Users\me>net use /?
NET USE
[Gerätename | *] [\\Computername\Freigabename[\Volume] [Kennwort | *]]
        [/USER:[Domänenname\]Benutzername]
        [/USER:[Domänenname im Punktformat\]Benutzername]
        [/USER:[Benutzername@Domänenname im Punktformat]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {Gerätename | *} [Kennwort | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want to use it on a python script ;)

Comment: Then you can use `os.system(...)` or `subprocess.popen([...], shell = True)` in python on the commands that work.